# Why is the "share-to" menu item gone in Android 4.0.3 PHONE HTC OneX

Tags: android, icons, contextmenu

**UPDATE

So far this only happens on the HTC OneX using Android 4.0.3**

I have two **share-to** menu items in the android share menu.

When the user shares an image from android gallery, my app displays two
icons so user can have easy access to two different part of my app. 
See picture.

This works fine in API v8, but in API v15 on ***a real device*** one of them is missing. API v15 emulator is ok!

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` this two `Activity's` set an icon in the share menu.

```
 - ActivityMainLauncher   
 - ActivityQuickLauncher
```

The images are places in the **hdpi**, **mdpi**, **ldpi** folders.
The size is 72,48,36 pixels and they are **PNG** images.
Photoshop shows same resolution 72,009 for all three images.
**UPDATE

added drawable-xhdpi folder for 96pix, but I have still only one item the: "SPRiiD"**

This behavior is so strange, I don't know where to start debug.
I think there is something new in the API v15 that I have overseen?

Image of emulator API v15 correctly showing the two choices.

[image]

This is my **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    package="com.carlsberg.dumbo"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="0.83" >

<!-- android:versionCode as the basis for identifying the application internally and handling updates, -->
<!-- android:versionName to users as the application's version -->
<permission
    android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission> -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_gallery"
    android:label="@string/string_app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityMainLauncher"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_gallery"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:targetActivity=".ActivityMainLauncher" />

    <activity
        android:name=".gallery.ActivityGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_gallery"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name_gallery"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="com.carlsberg.dumbo.GalleryActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityQuickLauncher"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_gallery"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name_quick_launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".send.ActivitySend"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityRemoveFriend"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.history.TabActivityHistoryLauncher"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.history.ActivityTabGroup1" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.history.ActivityTabGroup2" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.history.ActivityHistoryOutgoing" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo.history.ActivityHistoryIncoming" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityLogin"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityAddFriend"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityAcceptFriend"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/string_app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Preferences" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".send.TabActivityActivityHelpSend"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>


    <service
        android:name=".IntentServiceSendFiles"
        android:label="@string/string_sendFileService" >

    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".IntentServiceGetFilesFromPc"
        android:label="@string/string_getFileService" >
    </service>        
    <service
        android:name=".IntentServiceGetFiles"
        android:label="@string/string_getFileService" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".ServiceBootCompleated"
        android:label="@string/string_batchtester" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".IntentServiceGetFriendList"
        android:label="@string/string_listupdater" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".IntentServiceUpdateFriendList"
        android:label="@string/string_listupdater" >
    </service>
    <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" >

        <!-- Handle retry events -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />

            <category android:name="com.carlsberg.dumbo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".myBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name=".contentprovider.UserContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.carlsberg.dumbo.contentprovider" >
    </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: added drawable-xhdpi folder for 96pix, but I have still only one item the: "SPRiiD"

Comment: This is a long shot, but what happens if you add `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` to the `<uses-sdk />` tag of your manifest?

Comment: That made no deference im afraid

Comment: maybe its my computer setup, but for testing i create a simple new android project to test with same result

Comment: This only happens on HTC One X phone, every other phone I try this on its working ok. See further discussions

Comment: In my process of finding a solution i sent HTC an E-Mail about this, maybe im foreheaded but what the hell

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time a manufacturer/carrier ROM has broken something in Android. One of the many reasons people like myself prefer AOSP and ROMs much closer to it, like CyanogenMod.

Comment: @Karakuri yes of course will try the CyanogenMod. btw got an answer from HTC support and they could not open the link (to this question) and wanted me to describe in the e-mail what problem i have. I gave up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied the relevant part of your manifest and created a test project:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMainLauncher"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/string_app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityQuickLauncher"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/string_app_name_quick_launcher"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Simple activity implementations:

```
public class ActivityQuickLauncher extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public class ActivityMainLauncher extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And it works:

[image: Android 4.1.1]
[image: Android 4.0.3]

Android 4.1.1 (Galaxy Nexus) and Android 4.0.3 (Archos G9 A70).

Comment: I have HTC one X using Android 4.0.3. I have tried it on a galaxy  s3 using 4.0.3 and everything was ok. I'm thinking this can be a Bug in the 4.0.3 against HTC's hardware.

Comment: I guess the HTC one X is kind of 'forced' to be buggy: http://www.androidauthority.com/htc-one-x-multitasking-problem-apps-killed-off-86498/

Comment: Tried it on my friends OneX phone 4.0.3 . And it shows same bug as my HTC OneX

Comment: So this is definitly a bug in HTC One X's firmware :(

Comment: so far it looks like a bug. The fact that it's working in the emulator but not on the HTC hardware